# How can my users send money between each others in my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I was wondering if it's possible for the users of my app to send money between each other with Stripe?

I looked over the Stripe documentation but I didn't find any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be called a Peer-to-Peer payment.

And to my best knowledge Stripe does not support this via a direct API, the closest solution would be use Stripe Connect, which is a payment routing mechanism.

In order to integrate a payment API with flutter you should use a plugin.

On `flutter.dev` there are a few packages that support Stripe, please see:

- https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_sdk
- https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment

Comment: thanks for your response but my question was to know if those packages allows my users to send money between each others

Comment: @SofianeLyno Updated my answer to better answer you question.

Comment: You're welcome I hope I was able to help you. Unfortunately this tasks looks a bit complicated to accomplish due to compliance, regulations and fees involved, Do mark this question as solved if it resolved your query, so we can help other who have a similar question in the future

Comment: What do you think about this workaround ? User1 send money with Stripe to an intermediate  and then this intermediate send the money to the user

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to answer that, Stripe is not available in my country. But that's is what Stripe Connect is supposed to do so it should work, but this may be in violation of the Stripe Terms of Service, I suggest reaching out to Stripe support to get a more comprehensive answer to this

Comment: @SofianeLyno, I am looking for the same issue. Have you found a solution for it?